# Mouse continues "dragging" or "highlighting" after I release left button

Tags: arch-linux, mouse, highlighting, drag-and-drop

I just moved over to Antergos (Arch-based) from Ubuntu with XFCE and Awesome WM. I use a HP laptop with a touchpad.

When I hold down the left mouse button to highlight text or drag an icon, the drag or highlight action continues *for a short amount of time after I release the left button*.

(More annoying, the amount of time this "phantom left button" persists seems to be proportional to how long I held it. If I held down the left button for several seconds, it continues selecting text or dragging for 2-3 seconds after that. If I do a very short click and release, the "phantom button" effect is barely noticeable. This behavior has me convinced that this is supposed to be some kind of feature?)

I do not know what this feature is called, making it difficult to Google my problem. It's also the first time I've encountered it.

This is my `70-synaptics.conf`:

```
~ $ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "TapButton2" "2"
        Option "TapButton3" "3"
    Option "LockedDragTimeout" "0"
    Option "MaxTapTime" "0"
    Option "TapAndDragGesture" "0"
EndSection
```

This is my `synclient -l`:

```
~ $ synclient -l
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1661
    RightEdge               = 5367
    TopEdge                 = 1412
    BottomEdge              = 4510
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 0
    MaxTapMove              = 247
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 0
    ClickTime               = 0
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 112
    HorizScrollDelta        = 112
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0356189
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 0
    RTCornerButton          = 0
    RBCornerButton          = 0
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 2
    TapButton3              = 3
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 1
    ClickFinger3            = 1
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 0
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 28
    VertHysteresis          = 28
    ClickPad                = 0
```

Comment: It might be called kinetic scrolling, or Synaptics Coasting Speed. You may have a specific synaptics driver installed that you can control with `synclient`.

Comment: @meuh Thanks for the help, I checked them up but that's not the issue.

Comment: @Juicy could you please run `xinit test 13` and show the output from the exact time when your touchpad is doing that "phantom scroll"?

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros I'm getting told `/usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server` when I try to run that. Can this be run when X is running?

Comment: Try to use `evtest /dev/input/eventX` where X is the event ID from your touchpad, you'll need to use it on a different TTY (Ctrl+Alt+2..5)... and add the  `Option     "FastTaps" "1"` to your `synaptics.conf` and try `Option "LockedDrags" "0"` too, let me know if one of those help please

Comment: Fist, to narrow the problem, just run `evtest` to test whether the button-up event itself comes delayed or rather some magic in the processing of the event. And: the right button behaves normally?

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros `evtest` shows that the release of the `BTN_LEFT` is delayed, ie: `BTN_LEFT` is still True while the so-called phantom button is going on.

Comment: @Philippos see comment above

Comment: @Juicy good, at least now we know how to search... could you please add some info about your Window Manager/ Desktop Env? And some info about the hardware... are you on a Lenovo?

Comment: @ChristopherDíazRiveros I'm using `xfce` as desktop environment, with `awesome` window manager on top. I'm using an EliteBook 840 HP Laptop.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem (1) when using a different desktop environment and (2) when booting from a different source like a live CD. This could also be a hardware defect.

Answer (score 2):

From Synaptics [man](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html#sect3) page

> Option "ClickTime" "integer"
>
> The duration of the mouse click generated by tapping. Property: "Synaptics Tap Durations"

I guess here is the problem since your config has 100 in the value, maybe you should set it to 10 or even 1?

PS. try with every option that has the `Synaptics Tap Durations` label in the [man](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html#sect3) page, if the first one is not the problem I'm pretty sure that one of the other 4 should be

Comment: I gave that I try, unfortunately it didn't change anything. I tried setting `ClickTime` to 10, 1 and 0. I've updated my `synclient -l` output in my question.

Comment: Try adding `CoastingSpeed` to 0

Comment: Have you tried `libinput` I can't tell if that works on awesome wm

Comment: Gave it a try as well. Unfortunately I'm going to have to assume hardware failure at this point. I'm going to try to put my HD in other laptop when I get my hand on one to see if there's an issue. Thanks for the help :)